# dhcpv6 - stateful VS stateless, what is difference between it?

Tags: dhcp, dhcpv6

Can someone explain me, what is difference between DHCPv6 Stateful and Stateless? I was looking on the net and, surprisingly, I found only the remains of information but some general comparison or description of the differences between them did not find.
If I'm correct:

- Stateful - Needs DHCPv6 server to get IP, DNS, etc.
- Stateless - DHCPv6 server is not needed. In this mode, host getting configuration (IP, DNS, etc.) from router ads.

Right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A **stateful** address assignment involves someone keeping track of the *State*. Which is to say, some system exists that provides a log that certain IP addresses were assigned to certain MAC addresses. DHCP / DHCPv6 keeps track of such information.

A **stateless** address assignment does not keep track of what has or hasn't been assigned. It simply determines what address it should use on a particular network (to include possibly [picking it at random after determining the prefix](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4941#section-1)) and uses a system like [Duplicate Address Detection (DAD)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4862#section-5.4) to see if it inadvertently selected an address already in use.

In a *Stateless* assignment scenario, there is no server or device which keeps a running log of what IP addresses have been assigned and what IP addresses are remaining, available to be assigned. The mentality in a Stateless assignment scenario is: *Pick an IP address. If it happens to be in use, pick another one*.

TLDR:  **Stateful** requires a DHCP server to have been configured to hand out addresses. While **Stateless** address assignment simply requires the Router/Default-Gateway to understand and implement [RFC 4862](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4862)

Your assertion is essentially correct.

Comment: please provide an interfaces configuration examples, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

**Stateful configuration**

Stateless configuration (also known as SLAAC-StateLess AutoConfiguration)
The stateful version of DHCPv6 is pretty much the same as for IPv4. Our DHCPv6 server will assign IPv6 addresses to all DHCPv6 clients and it will keep track of the bindings. In short, the DHCPv6 servers knows exactly what IPv6 address has been assigned to what host.

**Stateless configuration**

Stateless works a bit different. The DHCPv6 server does not assign IPv6 addresses to the DHCPv6 clients, this is done through "autoconfiguration." The DHCPv6 server is only used to assign information that autoconfiguration doesn’t….stuff like a domain-name, multiple DNS servers and all the other options that DHCP has to offer.